# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have my wcf service and it runs fine. 
Then from my asp.net application I am trying to connect to this service. Everything is ok, request from asp.net is received in service (as I can debug code) and then when it returns to client I have the following error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly
```

My contract on WCF service is as follows:

```
[OperationContract()]
WCFResponseGetAllProducts GetAllProducts(WCFRequestGetAllProducts request);
```

And WCFResponseGetAllProducts , WCFRequestGetAllProducts  classes have [DataContract] attributes. Members of those classes have [DataMember] attribute.

However when I added another method to my contract:

```
[OperationContract()]
int Test();
```

then I can execute it from asp.net mvc application without a problem. Can someone please help me?
PS. I host my wcf service in default web server in visual studio 2010 at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. 
In my response object of type WCFREsponseGetAllProducts I had the following property

```
[DataMember]
public IQueryable<Product> Products {get;private set;}
```

The problem was that **IQueryable is not serializable** . I've changed it to Collection and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have resolved your issue, but I can still offer the advice  to take a look at using the [Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to figure out what goes wrong in situations like these.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the `WCFResponseGetAllProducts` being returned? I've encountered an issue previously due to the quantity of data that a method was returning.

Try adjusting the `web.config` file for your service by looking for the attributes `maxArrayLength`, `maxBytesPerRead`, `maxDepth`, `maxNameTableCharCount` and `maxStringContentLength` and increasing them.

You'll also need to do the same for the attributes in the `configuration > system.serviceModel > bindings > wsHttpBinding` section of the `web.config` file for your asp.net application, as well as (possibly) the `maxBufferPoolSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` values.

Comment: Apologies for the answer being slightly vague as to which values, specifically, you need to change - it's late here and I may've had a glass of wine or two =)